# Derivation of ELBO upon the Existence of Conditional Latent Variable Model

Tags: probability-distributions, divergence-operator, upper-lower-bounds

I am reading the recently published paper from DeepMind, ["Neural Scene Representation and Rendering"](https://deepmind.com/documents/211/Neural_Scene_Representation_and_Rendering_preprint.pdf) and especially its "Supplementary Materials".

Following is the page 1 and it's pretty hard for me to derive the upper-bound $F(\theta, \phi)$ equal to $-L(\theta) + \sum KL_{divergence}$

I think there might be more implicit steps to get to the conclusion but can't find something nicely fit deriviation passage.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

[image]